# How to force some views to rotate during orientation change but leave others as they are?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

To simplify, I'd like to create an activity which consists of two different views (e.g. button and image). And I want only one of them to rotate on orientation change while other to be orientation-independent.
I've found a lot about iOS case but nothing about Android.
Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very simple, just add `screenOrientation` to the activity (the one you don't want to rotate on orientation change) in the manifest file like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

All other activities will automatically rotate on orientation change.

Comment: It's not about activities. It's about different views on the same activity. E.g. imagine an "Evacuation scheme" - the whole map should not be rotated (it well fits the horizontal orientation) But the text on pictograms and button icons should be rotated according to the orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You can control what happens during orientation change on each activity.
[OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html)

Comment: But this will cause lots of boilerplate code. In my real application I've got lots of views on lots of activities and some of this views should not change on device rotating.

Comment: In your original post you claimed two views. Now you have lots of views. Decide what it is you have and what you need when posting your question. That being said...  Adding listeners and code to handle events differently is what it is all about. You can control the activity from the manifest as Kjartan suggested, or you can respond to the orientation change with code. If it gets to where you have repeated code, put the code in a class or interface and utilize it in an oop manner.

Answer (score 0):

Make two layout file and change int it as per your requirement and put in layout-land and layout folder.

**layout-land for Landscape View.**

**layout for portrait view.**

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand you. You mean there's a way to create 2 orientation layout files and specify that view1 on portrait orientation shoud be rotated on 90 degree? Is it possible? how?

Comment: Make two layout . For potrait and landscape and put it in two diff folder as per your req.

Comment: And what should I write in one of these layouts to draw one of views rotated on 90 degree?